# Show that, if $P(A\mid C)> P(B\mid C)$ and $P(A\mid C^c)> P(B\mid C^c)$, then $P(A)>P(B)$.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Any help with this question would be appreciated. I have trouble with anything related to $p(a\mid b)$.

Comment: What does Cc mean?

Comment: Maybe you mean $C^c$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Either $C$ or $C^c$ happens. Conditioning on whether $C$ or $C^c$ happens, we can see that
$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A ~|~ C) \mathbb{P}(C) + \mathbb{P}(A ~|~ C^c) \mathbb{P}(C^c) \\ \mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(B ~|~ C) \mathbb{P}(C) + \mathbb{P}(B ~|~ C^c) \mathbb{P}(C^c)$$
These expressions are symmetric. But whether or not $C$ happens, event $A$ happens with higher probability than event $B$ (i.e. both of the conditional probabilities are higher for $A$ than for $B$). What does this say about $\mathbb{P}(A)$ compared to $\mathbb{P}(B)$?